# Constructor base dependency injection not working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, spring-bean

It's my first time encountering this error that says

`Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.team.zah.blog.service.Impl.PostServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.team.zah.blog.repository.PostRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.team.zah.blog.repository.PostRepository' in your configuration.`

I can't fathom the problem here as I've clearly used the lombok annotation:
`@AllArgsConstructor` in my class

Class code here:

```
package com.team.zah.blog.service.Impl;

import com.team.zah.blog.dto.PostDTO;
import com.team.zah.blog.model.Post;
import com.team.zah.blog.repository.PostRepository;
import com.team.zah.blog.service.PostService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    private PostRepository postRepository;
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Override
    public PostDTO create(PostDTO postDTO) {
        Post post = modelMapper.map(postDTO, Post.class);
        Post savedPost = postRepository.save(post);
        return modelMapper.map(savedPost, PostDTO.class);
    }
}
```

I tried to manually do it like this

```
    @Autowired
    public void setPostRepository(PostRepository postRepository) {
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void setModelMapper(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }
```

but I still get the problem of missing bean.

I wonder what the problem here is?

Comment: Nothing to do with constructor, the error is quite explicit - spring can't find `PostRepository`. How did you declare it? Could it be in a package not scanned by spring?

Comment: @Chaosfire declared it the standard way.

under package com.team.zah.blog.repository;

public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {}

and that's about it

Comment: @devash is it annotated with `@Repository` and is the package included in the component scan paths? Are all required Spring Boot dependencies in the class path?

Comment: @knittl Some senior said annotating it with @Repository is redundant because SimpleJpaRepository.class is already annotated with `@Repository` if you've browsed the JpaRepository Interface. But yeah, for some reason I tried annotating it with @Repository, but the problem's still there. As for component scan paths, that's the first time i've heard of that and also dependencies class path. Let me check on that sir :)

Comment: Add a public default constructor in your PostRepository class.
```public PostRepository() {}```

Comment: @DONGMOBERNARDGERAUD I can't with an interface sir. My PostRepository is an interface that extends `JpaRepository` interface

Comment: @knittl all required spring boot dependencies are in my class path sir

Comment: Also, remove ```@Autowired``` above your setters. ```@Autowired```  is used for dependency injection

Comment: Please can you post your PostRepository ? I want to test it

Comment: @DONGMOBERNARDGERAUD here sir https://pastebin.com/E8wH18WA. Dependency: Spring Data Jpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and final fields.

1. Repository

```
package com.team.zah.blog.repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.team.zah.blog.model.Post;

public interface PosRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

}
```

2. Service

```
package com.team.zah.blog.service.Impl;

import com.team.zah.blog.dto.PostDTO;
import com.team.zah.blog.model.Post;
import com.team.zah.blog.repository.PostRepository;
import com.team.zah.blog.service.PostService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    private final PostRepository postRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Override
    public PostDTO create(PostDTO postDTO) {
        Post post = modelMapper.map(postDTO, Post.class);
        Post savedPost = postRepository.save(post);
        return modelMapper.map(savedPost, PostDTO.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think I resolved the problem here. But I can't pin point exactly the issue that made me post this amateurish question. I'm suspecting dependency issue though I'm not sure. Or it could be because of my `application.properties` incorrect configuration.

Here is my `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.database=postgresql

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/blog?autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = @@@@@@@@

spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this error is because on construct from lombok dont has que annotation @Autowired.

Why do you try this:

```
    @Service
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    private final PostRepository postRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public PostServiceImpl(PostRepository postRepository, ModelMapper, modelMapper) {
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this sir! But I was told spring automatically injects dependencies if you have single constructor with all arguments in it, so using `@Autowired` is not needed for it